# AWS Lambda Logging log4j2.properites

Tags: java, aws-lambda, log4j2

I am trying to write log4j2 configuration using log4j2.properties to log to cloudwatch. The configuration using log4j2.xml is working but the configuration via log4j2.properties is not working.
Below is my log4j2.properties
*

```
packages=com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.log4j2 
appenders=Lambda
appender.Lambda.type=Lambda
appender.Lambda.name = Lambda
appender.Lambda.layout.type=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
appender.Lambda.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} <%X{AWSRequestId}> %-5p %c{1}:%m%n
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = Lambda
rootLogger.appenderRef.Lambda.ref = Lambda
```

- 

Has anybody tried to configure using properties file? I am getting the below error in Cloudwatch

```
ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class 
com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.log4j2.LambdaAppender for element 
Lambda: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for 
class com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.log4j2.LambdaAppender 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class 
com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.log4j2.LambdaAppender
```

Comment: is it resolved? encountering the same problem.

Comment: No. Still looking for inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency for that appender

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```